# Can Visual Studio 2010 be installed with Visual Studio 2008 side by side?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS Team System 2008 and gonna install VS 2010 Express editions.

Comment: But dont expect to get out of the box support for TFS 2010 (if you choose to install) with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Quite well. I've used exactly that configuration with no problems at all.

Comment: Sure can, I have found conversion of projects is even very nice. :)

Comment: "Conversion of projects" is often changing `Version="7.10"` to `Version="8.10"` :)

Answer (score 5):

Sure; I have 2002, 2003, 2005, 2008, and 2010 all installed. Visual Studio even comes with a utility so when you open a solution, it figures out which version it should be opened with and uses the right one

Comment: Your hard drive must be enormous. It would take me 3 days to get all of these installed - it's a day to repave and I'm only using '08 and '10, with all their supporting utilities...

Answer (score 2):

Yes u can use them 
i tested this combination on both win2k8 and win 7 ( 64bit also)

I havent come across any problem. Infact i am succesfully able to open a solution that is developed using VS2008 in VS2010 RC

Answer (score 0):

Theres no problem if you install vs2008 and vs2010rc side by side. (Win7-64, win7-32, win2k8). it also works with SQL Management Studio.