# Can I install Visual studio 2010 and 2008 together?

Tags: visual-studio

I need both of them on one computer, first for educational purposes and second for work. Will there be compability problems?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879913/will-installing-visual-studio-2010-beta-side-by-side-with-vs2008-cause-problems

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio 2010 be installed with Visual Studio 2008 side by side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627329/can-visual-studio-2010-be-installed-with-visual-studio-2008-side-by-side)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. I have both of them installed side by side without any issues

Comment: +1 Thought you might like another badge :) Oh, and it was the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

They should work together fine.  Just be sure to install them in order from oldest to newest.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine, I have both installed on my current machine.

But just as an fyi, 2008 wasn't designed for Windows Vista/7, so it might throw up a warning or two when installing.

Comment: I've installed 2008 on both with no hassles.

Answer (score 1):

Aye, it's possible.  They install to different directories, and operate on different files, so no problem should be caused by having them both installed.  (I have Visual Basic 05 and 08 on the same machine)