# how to installation suggesion for mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

In my system i have mvc2 and Vs2008(licensed version).I am trying to learn mvc4. if i intall using this link [link][1] will it overwrite my VS 2008 to Vs 2012?  I am still middle of some project with MVC2. basically i want another installtion seperatly vs2012.any suggesions?

Comment: I think what you're asking is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087567/can-i-install-visual-studio-2010-and-2008-together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2012 & VS2008 will run along side each other; You'll just get two VS folders in your applications folder (and a VS2012 Projects folder added to My Documents).

The only thing you need to be careful with is opening the project up in VS2012 (as it will want to up-convert it). but there is an option to make a backup usually (or you can do so yourself before trying it).