# Visual Studio 2008 RTM and Visual Studio 2010 RTM MVC2 exist side-by-side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel and Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition version 9.0.30729.1 SP, both on the same machine, which is running Windows 7.  I need to edit an MVC2-based solution using VS 2008.  (I realize MVC2 is built into VS 2010.)  If I install AspNetMVC2_VS2008.exe (MVC2 for VS 2008) then will I mess up my VS 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio 2010 be installed with Visual Studio 2008 side by side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627329/can-visual-studio-2010-be-installed-with-visual-studio-2008-side-by-side)

Comment: @ChrisF: Not a duplicate because OP is asking if installing just MVC2 for his already-installed VS 2008 will cause problems with his already-installed VS 2010.

Comment: @qstarin - 2008 and 2010 can coexist regardless of the extensions installed.

Answer (score 1):

It should not cause you any problems, they co-exist peacefully in my experience.  I have installed MVC2 for VS2008 after VS2010 was installed and I had no problems, but I can't be certain my Visual Studio version numbers were exactly identical to yours.